# Derive from `boost::static-visitor` to remove code duplication

Tags: c++, templates, boost, boost-mpl, boost-variant

In one of my projects I'm using `boost-variant` excessively. At some point I exceeded the maximum number of template parameters (20) for `boost-variant`. Hence, I derived the following solution by linking several `boost-variant` Types together like a linked-list.

```
#include <boost/variant.hpp>
#include <iostream>

template<int T> struct A {
    const int value = T;
};

typedef boost::variant<
    A<20>,A<21>,A<22>,A<23>,A<24>,A<25>,A<26>,A<27>,A<28>,A<29>,A<30>,A<31>,A<32>,A<33>,A<34>,A<35>,A<36>,A<37>,A<38>,A<39>
> NextVar;

typedef boost::variant<
    A<1>,A<2>,A<3>,A<4>,A<5>,A<6>,A<7>,A<8>,A<9>,A<10>,A<11>,A<12>,A<13>,A<14>,A<15>,A<16>,A<17>,A<18>,A<19>,NextVar
> TVar;

struct PrintVisitor : public boost::static_visitor<std::string> {
    result_type operator()(const NextVar& n) {
        return n.apply_visitor(*this);
    }

    template<int T>
    result_type operator()(const A<T>& a)  {
        return std::to_string(a.value);
    }
};

struct IntVisitor : public boost::static_visitor<int> {
    result_type operator()(const NextVar& n) {
        return n.apply_visitor(*this);
    }

    template<int T>
    result_type operator()(const A<T>& a) {
        return a.value;
    }
};

template<int I>
struct AddVisitor : public boost::static_visitor<int> {
    result_type operator()(const NextVar& n) {
        return n.apply_visitor(*this);
    }

    template<int T>
    result_type operator()(const A<T>& a) {
        return a.value+I;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char **args) {
    TVar x = A<35>(); 
    PrintVisitor v1;
    std::cout << x.apply_visitor(v1) << std::endl;
    IntVisitor v2;
    std::cout << x.apply_visitor(v2) << std::endl;
    AddVisitor<10> v3;
    std::cout << x.apply_visitor(v3) << std::endl;
}
```

I was really surprised how well this workaround solved my problem. Still there was a grain of salt. For every visitor I had to include the line:

```
result_type operator()(const NextVar& n) {
    return n.apply_visitor(*this);
}
```

Which seems to be a kind of unnecessary code duplication. Getting even worse, if I'm in need of 60 or even more types in `boost-variant`. My try was to define a common base class for all of my visitors:

```
template<typename T>
struct BaseVisitor : public boost::static_visitor<T> {
    result_type operator()(const NextVar& n) {
        return n.apply_visitor(*this);
    }
};
```

I thought, that deriving from `BaseVisitor` like shown below would solve the problem:

```
struct PrintVisitor : public BaseVisitor<std::string> {
    template<int T>
    result_type operator()(const A<T>& a)  {
        return std::to_string(a.value);
    }
};
```

But instead the compiler complains:

```
template-argument for "const A<T> &" could not be derived from "T19"
```

What might be the closest workaround for this kind of problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you could simply increase this limit of 20 fixed by [`BOOST_MPL_LIMIT_LIST_SIZE`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/limit-list-size.html).

About your code: even if it compiles, `BaseVisitor::operator()` will make an infinite recursion besause of `*this` considered as a BaseVisitor at that moment.
To avoid that, you can use CRTP to have the good `derived()` instead:

```
template<class Derived, typename T>
struct BaseVisitor : public boost::static_visitor<T> {
    using typename boost::static_visitor<T>::result_type;

    Derived & derived() { return static_cast<Derived &>(*this); } 

    result_type operator()(const NextVar& n) {
        return n.apply_visitor( derived() );
    }
};
```

Then bringing this same `operator()` into the scope (otherwise hidden by the new one) of your derived classes (as well as `result_type` needed for template classes).

**[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dbe6d952a6b3783f)**

## Without aliases

As said in the comments, the aliases have to be written in each derived class. To get rid of it, we can gather the two `operator()`s at the same level in the base class, and name the derived function differently (`visit` here):

```
template<class Derived, typename T>
struct BaseVisitor : public boost::static_visitor<T> {
    using typename boost::static_visitor<T>::result_type;

    Derived & derived() { return static_cast<Derived &>(*this); } 

    result_type operator()(const NextVar& n) {
        return n.apply_visitor( derived() );
    }
    template<int I>
    result_type operator()(const A<I>& a)  {
        return derived().visit(a);
    }
};
```

Leaving us with:

```
struct PrintVisitor : public BaseVisitor<PrintVisitor, std::string> {
    template<int I>
    std::string visit(const A<I>& a)  {
        return std::to_string(a.value);
    }
};
```

**[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5a7965b3c1aee7fe)**

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply and your nice solution. Unfortunately, I have some restrictions and cannot use `BOOST_MP_LIMIT_LIST_SIZE`. Your solution is definitely working. CRTP is still not so obvious to me as it should. :-)

I wonder if it is possible to remove the clutter (template alias code) in the derived classes?

Comment: @FrankSimon Except lines 31 and 44 of the demo (not template classes), no. But by modifying our code a little bit... see edition.

Comment: Really awesome. It would take me some time to digest your solution. Many thanks. I'll use it in my production code.